# Option to tell Toad to never split a file which contains multiple objects?

Tags: oracle, toad

Is there an option to tell it to stop prompting me to split a file which contains multiple objects when opening .sql files from an edit window?  I never want to split the file!

Comment: When you perform which action?

Comment: @Phil When opening files.  When I am in an edit window and want to open a number of files I have to answer yes or no once for each file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Toad 10.6, it's in View `=>` Toad Options `=>` Editor `=>` Open/Save `=>` Opening files: Never split files

Comment: Definitely an irritating "feature" of Toad :p

Comment: Thank you sweet baby Jesus with your Baby Einstein educational toys!

Comment: It's the same for Toad 9.7